# Missing tab name and tab names doesn't change on android studio

Tags: java, android, intellij-idea, tabs

I have my main acitivty which opens SearchActivity with tabs, I did 3 tabs I see only 2 when I run the app and the tab names dont change from Tab 1, Tab 2 to what I configured.

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    //Open search window
    Button button = findViewById(R.id.buttonSearch);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        /**
         * Called when a view has been clicked.
         *
         * @param v The view that was clicked.
         */
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            openSearchActivity();
        }
    });
}

public void openSearchActivity() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, SearchActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

}

public class SearchActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_search);
    SectionsPagerAdapter sectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(this, getSupportFragmentManager());
    ViewPager viewPager = findViewById(R.id.view_pager);
    viewPager.setAdapter(sectionsPagerAdapter);
    TabLayout tabs = findViewById(R.id.tabs);
    tabs.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
    FloatingActionButton fab = findViewById(R.id.fab);

    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .setAction("Action", null).show();
        }
    });
}

public class SectctionPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
    /**
     * Constructor for {@link FragmentPagerAdapter} that sets the fragment manager for the adapter.
     * This is the equivalent of calling {@link #( FragmentManager , int)} and
     * passing in {@link #BEHAVIOR_SET_USER_VISIBLE_HINT}.
     *
     * <p>Fragments will have {@link Fragment#setUserVisibleHint(boolean)} called whenever the
     * current Fragment changes.</p>
     *
     * @param fm fragment manager that will interact with this adapter
     * @deprecated use {@link #(FragmentManager, int)} with
     * {@link #BEHAVIOR_RESUME_ONLY_CURRENT_FRAGMENT}
     */
    public SectctionPagerAdapter(@NonNull FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    /**
     * Return the Fragment associated with a specified position.
     *
     * @param position
     */
    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                return new BuildingTabOne();
            case 1:
                return new BuildingTabTwo();
            case 2:
                return new BuildingTabThree();
            default:
                return null;
        }
    }

    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                return "T15";
            case 1:
                return "Y3";
            case 2:
                return "T21";
        }
        return null;
    }

    /**
     * Return the number of tabs available.
     */
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 3;
    }
}
```

}

Example one tab:

```
public class BuildingTabTwo extends Fragment {
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.building_tab_two, container, false);
        return view;
    }
}
```

what did I do wrong?

Edit: added layout:
Main:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".MainActivity">
    <Button
            android:text="Search"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/buttonSearch"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.919"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"/>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Search:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".SearchActivity">

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <TextView
                android:id="@+id/title"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:minHeight="?actionBarSize"
                android:padding="@dimen/appbar_padding"
                android:text="@string/app_name"
                android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.Widget.AppCompat.Toolbar.Title"/>

        <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
                android:id="@+id/tabs"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"/>
    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

    <androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/view_pager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"/>

    <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/fab"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
            android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
            app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email"/>
</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Tab layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent">

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Post your layout

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti added

Answer (score 0):

the tablayout and viewpager must be together. Can you try this code.

It should be something like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".SearchActivity">

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:minHeight="?actionBarSize"
            android:padding="@dimen/appbar_padding"
            android:text="@string/app_name"
            android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.Widget.AppCompat.Toolbar.Title" />

        <androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/view_pager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

            <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
                android:id="@+id/tabs"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="?attr/colorPrimary" />
        </androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager>
    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

    <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email" />
</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: you are using viewpager and tablayout separately. Just copy paste the whole code inside your layout xml. Inside Appbarlayout (inside your layout) put this code and try to run it.

Comment: I put the code as you said on search XML, actually when I ran it after the changes I had only blank activity, no tabs at all